# Centralizar cards em dispositivo móvel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Não estou conseguindo fazer com que esses *cards* fiquem centralizados quando no dispositivo mobile, já me disseram para eu usar media queries, porém nesse sentido eu teria que criar uma nova classe para atribuir o código css, ou seja, não estaria tirando proveito do que o *bootstrap* oferece. Há algum nome de classe que me possibilite realizar esse tipo de coisa.

**Segue o código:**

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <!--first card-->
      <div class="card mb-5 curadoria-card" style="width: 18rem;">

       <img src="img/festcasa/people-01.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

       <div class="card-body text-center">

        <h5 class="card-title"><strong style="color: #08979b; font-weight: bold">Nome da pessoa</strong><br/></h5>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Currículo em anexo</a>

       </div>

      </div>

     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <!--secondary card -->
      <div class="card mb-5" style="width: 18rem;">

       <img src="img/festcasa/people-02.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

       <div class="card-body text-center">

        <h5 class="card-title"><strong style="color: #08979b; font-weight: bold">Nome da pessoa</strong><br/></h5>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Currículo em anexo</a>

       </div>

      </div>

     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <!--third card-->
      <div class="card mb-5" style="width: 18rem;">

       <img src="img/festcasa/people-03.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

       <div class="card-body text-center">

        <h5 class="card-title"><strong style="color: #08979b; font-weight: bold">Nome da pessoa</strong><br/></h5>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Currículo em anexo</a>

       </div>

      </div>
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Notem que eles estão responsivos, porém não ficaram centralizados!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a classe nativa `.mx-auto` nos cards:

*Informações sobre classes de espaçamento você encontra na [documentação oficial](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/), em português*.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <!--first card-->
      <div class="card mb-5 curadoria-card mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">

       <img src="img/festcasa/people-01.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

       <div class="card-body text-center">

        <h5 class="card-title"><strong style="color: #08979b; font-weight: bold">Nome da pessoa</strong><br/></h5>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Currículo em anexo</a>

       </div>

      </div>

     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <!--secondary card -->
      <div class="card mb-5 mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">

       <img src="img/festcasa/people-02.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

       <div class="card-body text-center">

        <h5 class="card-title"><strong style="color: #08979b; font-weight: bold">Nome da pessoa</strong><br/></h5>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Currículo em anexo</a>

       </div>

      </div>

     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <!--third card-->
      <div class="card mb-5 mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">

       <img src="img/festcasa/people-03.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

       <div class="card-body text-center">

        <h5 class="card-title"><strong style="color: #08979b; font-weight: bold">Nome da pessoa</strong><br/></h5>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Currículo em anexo</a>

       </div>

      </div>
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: era exatamente disso que estava precisando, já estou lendo a `doc`, porém as vezes leio por demanda, o que exatamente irei utilizar. Vou dar uma lida no que me mandou!

Comment: Realmente não precisa ler toda a doc. Ele serve mais para referência quando precisa. Boa sorte!